# Sentry logger filter show actual loggers

Tags: python, django, logging, sentry

I setup a sentry at server. And created a several different loggers at raven, and when i log via this different loggers sentry displays that it`s different loggers, but at right column filter at logger section there only Any logger and not my existing loggers.
How to make a sentry filter to show actual loggers rather than meaningless any entry?
[image: HEre how it looks now]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bug in sentry. Was fixed in 3.5.9 version.